# Unity3d выдает ошибку об утечке

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте, на 2d сцене есть игровой объект управляемый игроком.
Если в момент когда на сцене кроме главного персонажа ничего нет, нажать на кнопку пауза, то все нормально и юнити не выдает в консоль ошибку, а если нажать паузу в момент когда на сцене кроме главного персонажа присутствуют другие игровые объекты, то юнити выдает такую ошибку в консоль:

Internal: JobTempAlloc has allocations that are more than 4 frames old - this is not allowed and likely a leak

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ее суть?

upd: словил ее появление после самоуничтожения префаба пули выпущенной игроком (самоуничтожается обычно вне видимости игровой камеры)

```
GameObject b = Instantiate(bullet, sp.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            Destroy(b, 4);
```

upd2: переделал метод стрельбы в Pool как подсказали в комментарии из обучающего ролика Unity, только вместо List использовал Stack. Но все равно ошибки появляются после уничтожения префаба пули в момент столкновения с врагом и нажатия после этих событий кнопки Пауза.
+ Обновил Юнити с 5.6.1f1 до 5.6.3p2 и все равно ошибка осталась на месте.

Код pool из обучающего ролика юнити:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class StackPool : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static StackPool current;
    public GameObject pooledObject;
    public int pooledAmount = 20;
    public bool allowGrowth = true;

    Stack<GameObject> pooledObjects;

    void Awake()
    {
        current = this;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        pooledObjects = new Stack<GameObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < pooledAmount; i++)
        {
            GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(pooledObject);
            obj.SetActive(false);
            pooledObjects.Push(obj);
        }
    }

    public GameObject Pop()
    {
        if (pooledObjects.Count > 0)
        {
            return pooledObjects.Pop();
        }

        if (allowGrowth)
        {
            GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(pooledObject);
            //pooledObjects.Push(obj);
            return obj;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void Push(GameObject obj)
    {
        pooledObjects.Push(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: возможно проблема [в самой юнити](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/jobtempalloc-error-appears-in-32-bit-standalone-build-output-log-if-trees-are-in-the-scene) .... хотя без подробностей с чем работаете и что на игровых объектах имеется мало что можно сказать

Comment: Сейчас проверил, оказывается эта ошибка включается когда префаб пули выпущенной из оружия главного персонажа покидает видимую область игровой камеры и самоуничтожается спустя 4 сек, данную величину я задал с помощью:
     GameObject b = Instantiate(bullet, sp.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            Destroy(b, 4);

Comment: Вообще для пуль  (да и не только для них) лучше используй пул объектов, вместо инстациирования и уничтожения оных. Видео: https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling  .... об этой технике на русском: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/MobileOptimizationScriptingMethods.html

Comment: Не используйте сырые билды типа 2017, их еще не достаточно тестами и заплатками покрыли. Используйте более стабильные из 5ой версии. Накачают, а потом вопросы сыпят. И качать надо последние версии, пропатченные. Следите за заплатками, там фиксят очень много ошибок, которые поступают от пользователей.

Comment: Та версия что я использую была скачана с оф сайта, так что сорри про все эти заморочки с версиями я не знал, но все равно спасибо :). буду переделывать под pool, а то слышал что если проект перенести на другую версию юнити будет куча глюков.